# How are Kounotori modules unbolted? Who or what does the unbolting?

Tags: iss, docking, jaxa

NASA Spaceflight's [Final JAXA H-II Transfer Vehicle bids farewell to ISS](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2020/08/final-h-ii-bids-farewell-to-iss/) says:

> Following CBM vestibule depressurization, 16 bolts that held the Kounotori 9 spacecraft to the Station were removed in **four stages of four bolts**. This officially marked the detachment of the vehicle from the ISS.

How was this unbolting accomplished? Where did the bolts go? Who or what did the unbolting? Were they explosive bolts or did someone use a wrench on them or were they motorized or something else?

If done via explosive bolts or motors, is it done under computer control, or does someone push a button or issue four separate commands for the four stages of unbolting, or is it just a "go" command and the four stages are implemented by an automated sequencer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The bolts are part of the Common Berthing Mechanism (CBM).

> The Common Berthing Mechanism (CBM) is a complex collection of
> latches, bolts, Ready to Latch (RTL) indicators ... and computers to
> control this equipment. This system can be operated by either the
> ground or the crew; extravehicular activities (EVAs) (i.e.,
> spacewalks) are not required to use this mechanism, unlike some of the
> truss attachment systems. Once a new module is close enough to the ISS
> (RTL), four latches on the ISS side (usually a Node module) are used
> to reach out and “grab” the incoming module and pull it closer.
> Alignment guides ensure the bolts and nuts of the mechanism are in
> line with each other. Once the latches have pulled the two halves
> together, bolts on the active CBM are extended into nuts on the
> passive CBM. Each of the 16 bolts has a preload of approximately 90 kN
> (20,230 lbs) of force on it after the bolting sequence is complete.

[image]

This diagram shows one of the four controller panel assemblies with its four associated bolts and one associated latch.

[image]

The CBMs are normally operated by the crew. The Personal Computer System (PCS) (aka ISS laptop) display used to control and monitor the CBMs is shown here.

[image]

The bolting stages are described here

> Bolting   is conducted   in   several   stages.      The   first stage acquires  all  16  bolts  and  their  mating  nuts  and torques
> them  to  an  “acquire  bolt  preload”  of  1500 pounds  (as  measured
> by  strain  gages  within  the bolts, and monitored by the CBM Bolt
> Controllers). After   the   preload   torque   is   complete, further torquing   is   discontinued   so   that   temperatures between
> the   passive   ring   and   active   ring   can equalize.    Once  the
> temperatures  are  equalized,the   torquing   operation   resumes. Bolts   are commanded,  in-groups  of  four,  through  several more
> torquing  stages,  proceeding  from  the  initial preload of 1500
> pounds up to a final load of 19,300pounds  per  bolt.    The  module
> is  then  in  its  fully berthed  position.

Here is a picture of the bolt actuator and a schematic showing a "ready to bolt" bolt.

[image]

[image]

For further reading: the document below "The Common Berthing Mechanism for ISS" is recommended.

References

- [The International Space Station - Operating an Outpost in the New
  Frontier](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/iss-operating_an_outpost-tagged.pdf)
- [The Common Berthing Mechanism for ISS](https://spacecraft.ssl.umd.edu/design_lib/ICES01-2435.ISS_CBM.pdf)
- [What do remotely-controlled bolts look like?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15023/6944)
- [Space Station Berthing Mechanisms](http://esmats.eu/amspapers/pastpapers/pdfs/2004/foster.pdf)
- Personal Notes

Comment: Wow even excellenter than when I commented previously! Thanks for the edits and all those other goodies!

Comment: I love how much freely available documentation exists for NASA related projects and standards.